# Moving XML parsing to server-side

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, xml-parsing

I need to parse an uploaded XML document on the server-side.  Now I have some code that works on the client-side, but I want to move it to server-side.  My client-side uses the FileReader API and its code looks like this:

```
reader.onload = function (e) {
        var InnerLibrary = new String(e.target.result);
        if (window.DOMParser) {
            parser = new DOMParser();
            xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(InnerLibrary, "text/xml");

            console.log("start of xmlDoc console log");
            console.log(xmlDoc);
            console.log("end of xmlDoc console log");

            $(xmlDoc).find('book').each(function () {
                console.log("book Found");
                console.log(($(this).attr("year")));
                version = ($(this).attr("year"));
            });
```

Now I had been led to use libxmljs per some other SO question that I can't seem to find right now.  But the person said that libxmljs would be better because then I can traverse the XML DOM object using find(), which insinuated you *can't* do that in xml2js.

I tried libxmljs but for some reason its causing me problems noted in this question here:
[The question where libxmljs causes problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544035/azure-deployment-error-with-libxmljs-for-node-js)

**so I'm asking, can I use this method of traversal in xml2js?**
(and by that I mean, using .find() .each() .attr(), basically everything used in this)

**If not, what method of finding the data should I do?**

**UPDATE:** I tried using xml2js yesterday and it turns out that it doesn't parse from an xml file into a string, it will only parse the xml out of a string.  So a bonus question would be:

**BONUS: Can I use the FileReader API on the server side?**

Comment: The problem that you mention is for Windows Azure where you cannot build native modules, which platform are you using.

Comment: The problem isn't with Windows Azure when regarding xml2js.  It is the problem when working with libxmljs.  You can bring in xml2js as a node module into the projects file structure and upload it just like any other node module for windows azure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery client side, it's probably most convenient for you to use server side as well. The port is found [here](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery), and it's actively maintained and used (1k downloads/day). Do note that by default that version `1.8.3` is installed, but versions up to `2.0.0` are also supported. This is how you'd specify the version you'd like to use:

```
var jquery = require('jquery');
var $ = jquery(null, '1.8.3');

// or use 2.0.0
var $ = jquery(null, '2.0.0');
```

I haven't tested *xml2js*, but since [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), and [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) are all jQuery functions, you might as well use the functionality to parse DOM, as you will have to have it installed to use those three functions. If you installed the module with `npm install jquery`, here's how you'd use it:

```
// create an instance of the library
var $ = require('jquery').create();

// use the same way as the browser
$(xml).find('book').each(function () {
  console.log('book found');
  console.log(($(this).attr("year")));
  version = ($(this).attr("year"));
});
```

Node also does not have the `FileReader` API because there is already a native filesystem module. All file I/O can be performed with the [`fs`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) library with `require('fs')`.

This is how you could read a file, and pass it to jQuery for parsing:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var $ = require('jquery').create();

fs.readFile('/document.xml', function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;

  $(data).find('book').each(function () {
    console.log('book found');
    console.log(($(this).attr("year")));
    var version = ($(this).attr("year"));
  });
});
```

This can also be done synchronously:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var $ = require('jquery').create();

var xml = fs.readFileSync('/document.xml');

$(xml).find('book').each(function () {
  console.log('book found');
  console.log(($(this).attr("year")));
  var version = ($(this).attr("year"));
});
```

If you don't want to use the Node implementation of jQuery, you could use the lower level APIs such as [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) and [htmlparser](https://github.com/tautologistics/node-htmlparser), but you won't be able to use the three functions you specified anyways.

**Edit:** There is a `parseXML()` in the Node implementation of jQuery, but it doesn't seem to work correctly. Here is an alternate solution using `xmldom`:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var $ = require('jquery').create();
var DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;

var xml = fs.readFileSync('/document.xml');
var doc = DOMParser.parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml');

$(doc).find('book').each(function () {
  console.log('book found');
  console.log(($(this).attr("year")));
  var version = ($(this).attr("year"));
});
```

Comment: Wow, this is amazing! Well done, you have answered every question I had.  If I could give you more rep, I would.  I will be using your suggesting as soon as I can.

Comment: Passing an XML string to `$()` attempts to parse it as HTML rather than XML and may have undesirable results. The correct method to use in jQuery is [`$.parseXML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

Comment: I noticed there was no `$.parseXML()` in the Node implementation, which is why I answered like so, but I will look further to see if I missed something.

Comment: I've added a solution with the Node implementation of `DOMParser`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always run a child process in node to run things like:

http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html

Or any other non-node implemented solution like sudhAnsu63 suggested. And process the output afterwards.

Answer (score -2):

you can use Cxml for parsing xml in C++

http://libxmlplusplus.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/html/ar01s02.html#id2504579

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/111243/Simple-C-XML-Parser

Once your xml is parsed you can use GetRootNode(), GetNextChild() to traverse through the xml file

Comment: Good to know but I'm looking for a javascript parser.

Comment: FYI javascript is a clientside scripting language.

Comment: then how is sax-js (what xml2js is designed with) made for node.js (the javascript server-side application)